# Python convert Hexadecimal Character to Respective Symbols?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, escaping

I'm trying to find a python package/sample code that can convert the following input "why+don%27t+you+want+to+talk+to+me" to "why+don't+you+want+to+talk+to+me".

Converting the Hex codes like %27 to ' respectively. I can hardcode the who hex character set and then swap them with their symbols. However, I want a simple and scalable solution.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use urllib's unquote function.

```
import urllib.parse
urllib.parse.unquote('why+don%27t+you+want+to+talk+to+me')
```